# do While loop trouble

Tags: java, string, loops, while-loop, or-operator

I am having trouble with my do-while statement. I created a do-while loop to ensure the only accepted input is "e" or "o" (not case sensitive), however, it continues the loop even though I inserted the desired input. Any help is appreciated!

[Current Code & Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l8yf.png)

Comment: you meant to loop on &&. And shouldn't post code as images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement:
`while(!side.equalsIgnoreCase("O") || !side.equalsIgnoreCase("E"));`
is always true

If you input `E` or `e`, this `!side.equalsIgnoreCase("E")` is false but this `!side.equalsIgnoreCase("O")` is true

If you input `O` or `o`, this `!side.equalsIgnoreCase("O")` is false but this `!side.equalsIgnoreCase("E")` is true

Since you are using `||`, `true || false` gives you `true` so the loop never ends

For every other input, both are true (`true || true`) which is also true

You need to replace it with:
`while(!side.equalsIgnoreCase("O") && !side.equalsIgnoreCase("E"));`

Comment: I had a different understanding in my head, so thank you for the explanation it cleared up my confusion.